# Keras Error on target shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras to build a model and I have the following structure,
The last layer in the model is a Dense Layer that generates a (?,27) tensor.

I then use a dataset where the target Y is a (100,27) numpy array. Here m=100, the train set.
When I do a model.fit with  the expected Y, I get the error,

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 27 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[195355., 344695., 300964., ..., 357266., 393302., 400001.],
       [282257., 174032., 321944., ...,      0.,      0.,      0.],
       [220870., 374021., 225629., ...,      0.,      0.,      ...
```

Comment: Mention those lines of code in the question by which you are (1).preparing numpy array to pass to model (2).Defining model input (3). Defining model output